# On which of the stack exchange sites can I ask this Question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Please guide me on which of the current Meta sites I could post the following question.

I have a RAM desktop DIMM whose Heat Sink wore off. See image.

[image: Img]

I'm trying to find out a reliable way to secure back the heat sink back properly.

Comment: You wouldn't ask that type of question *on* a Meta site... You'd ask on a main site.

Comment: there is a [list of sites with their brief descriptions](http://stackexchange.com/sites#name) one can choose from. For your question, I'd probably consider [Cooking](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/)... or maybe not

Answer (score 4):

Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about

```
    computer hardware
    computer software
    personal and home computer networking
```

[superuser](https://superuser.com/)
see FAQ 
[FAQ Superuser](https://superuser.com/faq)

Comment: Thanks, Ill head over there and get help.